# How to edit and validate power point document using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to edit and validate word or ppt document using selenium webdriver please help me

Comment: You need to explain what you've already tried or what research you've done. Your question is too broad as stated.

Comment: It is not possible. Selenium-WebDriver is for automating browsers, not Power Point.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/), Java API to interact with word, Excel and PowerPoint.